# Issue with comparing two string in Angular - 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I trying to create a if statement that should compare two string, but from same reason something is not working.

```
      console.log(this.selectedDay.split("/")[2])
      console.log(this.selectedMonth)

       if( this.selectedMonth !== this.selectedDay.split("/")[2]) {
         console.log("The strings are different")

       } else {
        console.log("The strings are the same")
       }
```

[image: Java script]

[EDIT]
when i manually comparing the two values the result is correct

```
 if( 'נובמבר 2018' !== 'נובמבר 2018') {
         console.log("The strings are different")

       } else {
        console.log("The strings are the same")
       }
```

[image]

[EDIT2]

Assigning the split result to a VAR

```
 const value1 = this.selectedMonth;
  const value2 = this.selectedDay.split("/")[2];

  console.log(value1)
  console.log(value2)

   if( value1 !== value2) {
     console.log("The strings are different")

   } else {
    console.log("The strings are the same")
   }
})
```

[image]

[Edit3]

I converted all the string to Array like the user @ConnorsFan suggested and this is what came up. Crazy..

```
      const value1 = this.selectedMonth;
      const value2 = this.selectedDay.split("/")[2];

      console.log(value1);
      console.log(value2);


      console.log(value1.split(""));
      console.log(value2.split(""));



       if( value1.valueOf() === value2.valueOf()) {
         console.log("The strings are the same")

       } else {
        console.log("The strings are diffrent")
       }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Do you maybe have whitespaces by mistake?

Comment: @GiladBar No, I doubled checked it.

Comment: Can you add the values for this.selectedDay?

Comment: can you try this.selectedMonth.localeCompare(this.selectedDay.split("/")[2]) != 0 maybe there is some issue with the encoding.

Comment: Try `console.log()` using `.valueOf()` or use it thus: `this.selectedMonth.valueOf() !== this.selectedDay.split("/")[2].valueOf()`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I added an edit

Comment: You are probably comparing a String Object with a string literal - hence my suggestion of `.valueOf()` which resolves this.

Comment: I tried every thing that you suggested nothing worked. Cant understand whats going on.

Comment: @Florian Did it, both of them are `strings`

Comment: Try `console.log(value1.split(""));` (and the same for `value2`). It will output the individual characters, maybe revealing something unexpected. You could even try `console.log(value1.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0)));` to see the character codes.

Comment: @ ConnorsFan of course it did

Comment: The problem was found. Thank you everybody.

Comment: That qualifies as "unexpected". :-)